# What does "refuting random 3CNF" formulas mean?

Tags: complexity-theory, logic

Intuitively, recall what 3CNF formulas mean:

Its a boolean formula with conjunctive normal form (i.e. formula of ANDs of clauses with ORs) with no more than three variables per conjunct.

I was reading a [paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4905-more-data-speeds-up-training-time-in-learning-halfspaces-over-sparse-vectors.pdf) that said:

> under a widely believed assumption that refuting random 3CNF formulas is hard, it is impossible to efficiently learn this class using ony $O(\frac{n}{\epsilon^2})$ examples.

however, I wasn't sure what "refuting random 3CNF formulas" even meant so I was having a hard time understanding the sentence. Someone know what that means?

Comment: see also research on the "SAT transition pt". alas there is not yet a good wikipedia article on the subj :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *random 3CNF* with $n$ variables and $m$ clauses is obtained by picking $m$ clauses uniformly at random among the $8\binom{n}{3}$ different clauses. It is known that there exists a constant $C$ such that when $m = Cn$, a random 3CNF is unsatisfiable with high probability; it is strongly suspected that there exists a best such constant $C$, which is known experimentally to be about $4.2$.

It seems, therefore, that if I give you a random 3CNF with $n$ variables and $100n$ clauses, it should be easy to prove that it's unsatisfiable (unless you're very unlucky). However, the best such algorithm, due to [Feige and Ofek](http://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v003a002/v003a002.pdf), only works for $m = \Omega(n^{1.5})$. The best *non-deterministic* algorithm, due to [Feige, Kim and Ofek](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4031385), only works for $m = \Omega(n^{1.4})$.

One can state many conjectures of the form "refuting random 3CNF formulas is hard". The weakest would state that for every $C > 0$, there is no polynomial time algorithm that, given a formula, answers either **unsatisfiable** or **don't know**, and (i) answers **unsatisfiable** with high probability when given a random 3CNF with $n$ variables and $Cn$ clauses, (ii) answers **unsatisfiable** only for unsatisfiable formulas.

Stronger conjectures would work for $n^{1+\epsilon}$ clauses for some $\epsilon > 0$, and for non-deterministic polynomial time algorithms.

Comment: so refuting a 3CNF formula is a statement wether there is an algorithm that can conclude wether the formula is satisfiable or not?

Comment: Not exactly. The algorithm should either declare "unsatisfiable" or "don't know", but most of the time it should declare "unsatisfiable", and it should never be wrong.

Comment: The only comment I have about ur definition of "refuting a 3CNF" formula is that your statement seems to be very precise (an algorithm in RP?), implying that "refuting a 3CNF" formula is a rigorously defined term. However, for me it sounds like that terminology isn't rigorous (because of the word refuting), or maybe I am wrong, it is a rigorous/technical term? Btw, thanks for your help :)

Comment: It's not a rigorous term, but when they mention a "widely believed assumption", they assume that you know what they're talking about, that is, there is a precise rigorous conjecture which is known as "refuting random 3CNF formulas is hard"; compare, for example, the "unique games conjecture". They should probably have cited some source stating this conjecture, for the sake of the coming generations, since in the future this conjecture might have a different name (or even be a theorem!).

Comment: side comment (probably super super super easy question), why are you multiplying by 8 in your counting argument?

Comment: Variables can appear positively or negatively.

Comment: You said that after say, $m > Cn$, a random 3CNF is unsatisfiable with high probability. But then you say the algorithms only work for $m \Omega(n^1.5)$ and $m \Omega(n^1.4)$. How is that not a contradiction to the statement that 3CNF is hard? It seems that refuting 3CNF is easy for $m > Cn$...right? Or what am I misunderstanding? I would guess that if $m > Cn$, there is an trivial algorithm that succeeds most of the time. If $m > Cn$ is true, then the algorithm should just say "unsatisfiable" and will get it right most of the time for a random instance of 3CNF. It seems too trivial...

Comment: The algorithm should never say **unsatisfiable** for a satisfiable instance. Refuting a random 3CNF when $m = 100n$ should be hard. Current algorithms only handle $m = \Omega(n^{1.5})$ (deterministic) and $m = \Omega(n^{1.4})$ (non-deterministic), which have many more clauses.

Comment: Condition (ii) that you wrote is just saying that if the algorithm returns an answer, then the answer is correct? i.e. if the algorithm returns an answer, then the boolean formula is indeed unsatisfiable? (i.e. it sound with high probability)?

And condition (i) is saying that when given an instance that is unsatisfiable (i.e. correct) then the algorithm answers that its unsatisfiable? i.e. the algorithm is complete with high probability?

Comment: Your interpretation of (ii) is misleading. The algorithm only has to be correct when it answers **unsatisfiable**. If it answers **don't know** then it is OK for the instance to satisfiable or unsatisfiable. As for (i), the algorithm can be deterministic, and there can be unsatisfiable instances on which it always returns **don't know**. But given a random instance (or equivalently a random unsatisfiable instance) it must answer **unsatisfiable** with high probability (over the choice of the instance).

Comment: I see now that my definition is different from the one that the paper uses. My definition comes from the paper of Feige, Kim, and Ofek, which I hope I remember correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I want to add some remarks that helped me understand (conceptually) much better what "*refuting* 3CNF" formulas meant (and thanks Yuval, his answer and discussion was useful, make sure you read it!).

First, want to point out what *refuting* means (this might have been an important (but easy to fix), confusion for me since English isn't my first language), *Refuting* means:

> prove (a statement or theory) to be **wrong** or **false**.

i.e. in the context of satisfiability, determining wether a formula is false (or unsatisfiable) is the same thing as *refuting* the (boolean) formula.

Hence, in this context, an algorithm A that refutes a random 3CNF (3-conjunctive normal form) formula means that the algorithm is able to determine wether the boolean formula is unsatisfiable or "it doesn't know".

A useful extract of the [paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4905-more-data-speeds-up-training-time-in-learning-halfspaces-over-sparse-vectors.pdf) I am reading discusses this more precisely on page 5. For reference here is a screen shot of that discussion:

[image]